# Hardware accelerated lossless recording on a 6700 XT using ffmpeg

Tags: linux-mint, ffmpeg, amd-graphics, video-encoding, recording

I'm trying to record my screen losslessly (or at near lossless quality) with hardware acceleration on a 6700 XT with ffmpeg. I'm running Linux Mint with the `5.14.14-051414-generic` kernel.

I've tried:

`ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f x11grab -video_size 2560x1440 -i :0 -r 60 -vf 'hwupload,scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 0 output.mp4`

`ffmpeg` says it's recording at 60 fps, but the recording is choppy and slightly miscolored. I'm assuming the color issue is from the color format nv12, but `rgb` or `rgb8` gives an error.

I've also tried using kmsgrab:

`ffmpeg -device /dev/dri/card0 -f kmsgrab -i - -vf 'hwmap=derive_device=vaapi,scale_vaapi=w=2560:h=1440:format=nv12' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 0 output.mp4`

But it gives the error:

```
[kmsgrab @ 0x558f001c8d80] Using plane 65 to locate framebuffers.
[kmsgrab @ 0x558f001c8d80] Failed to get framebuffer 127: Invalid argument.
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

The number after `Failed to get framebuffer` is usually `127` or somewhere from `134` to `136`.

I got these commands [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL,DR: I think you've mostly hit bugs in ffmpeg and/or other parts of the stack that seem be fixed by now.

Your first command:

`ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f x11grab -video_size 2560x1440 -i :0 -r 60 -vf 'hwupload,scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 0 output.mp4`

Works for me, on Debian Bookworm with ffmpeg 5.1 (I only changed the size to match my monitor), with no color issue and 60 fps, on the same GPU (6700 XT). So maybe there was (at the time) a bug somewhere in your version of ffmpeg or in VA-API drivers or something.

It does not use the highest quality, `-qp 0` may be out of the supported range for this encoder and subsequently ignored, apparently it falls back to a default value:

`No quality level set; using default (20).`

Values as low as `-qp 1` seem to be accepted, and may bring enough quality for your needs.

---

Regarding kmsgrab, note that using it requires either running as root, or having the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability set. This may well be the cause for your error, and a fix is to set the capability on ffmpeg:

`setcap cap_sys_admin=ep /usr/bin/ffmpeg`

This is not ideal for security, and will break when ffmpeg is updated, but it works, and your command line runs fine for me too.

Note also that using kmsgrab while also recording audio caused audio/video synchronization problems until at least ffmpeg 5.1:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8377

If you want to use it, you probably want to upgrade to ffmpeg 6, which in my experience fixed that last issue.

Answer (score 2):

Truly lossless encoding can only be done in software I think, but with higher bitrates it may look good enough.

Also the ffmpeg wiki says VAAPI is only supported partly for AMD GPUs.

But I suspect you currently might be using the CPU's integrated GPU anyway, which might lead to performance issues:

> If you have multiple usable devices in the same machine (for example, an Intel integrated GPU and an AMD discrete graphics card), they can be used simultaneously to decode different streams:
>
> ffmpeg -init_hw_device vaapi=intel:/dev/dri/renderD128 -init_hw_device vaapi=amd:/dev/dri/renderD129 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device intel -i ... -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device amd -i ...

Have you looked if there is more than one hw device available?

Try **ls /dev/dri/** to see which devices are available.

No matter if you used the right device or not, the **-qp 0** option probably will not work as intended, so try it with the exact commands given, and see if they give better results:

```
ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0 -vf 'hwupload,scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 24 output.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0 -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 24 output.mp4
```

With just the resolution changed, and if you found another hw device you can try to change this too.

Would be interested if you can get good quality with reasonable bitrates / file size, so please let me know if you were successful.

Btw the following is not using hw acceleration, but lossless encoding, so you might try this one too: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#lossless-recording

> To speed up the encoding process, you can use lossless encoding and disable advanced encoder options, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -color_range 2 output.mkv
```

> -crf 0 tells x264 to encode in lossless mode; -preset ultrafast advises it to do so fast. Note the use of libx264rgb rather than
> libx264; the latter would do a lossy conversion from RGB to yuv444p (8
> bit yuv444p is not enough to preserve 8 bit RGB, 10 bit YCbCr is
> needed). ...
>
> The encoder should be fast enough on most modern hardware to record
> without any framedrop, and even leave enough CPU headroom for other
> applications.
>
> If you're going to archive the recording or are concerned about file
> size, re-encode it losslessly again, but with a slower preset. ...

Comment: I tried recording with your examples, changing `-video_size 1920x1080` to `-video_size 2560x1440 -framerate 60`. ffmpeg says it's recording at 60 fps, but the video [is not at 60fps](https://lostxor.com/stack-exchange-video-test.mp4). Also the colors are [less vibrant than the original](https://lostxor.com/stack-exchange-colors.png).

Comment: What was the output of `ls /dev/dri/` ?  - I assume the colors from your desktop need to be converted for video, so it may help using 10bit encoding **or** just try this instead and check if the colors are better: `ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -color_range 2 output.mkv`

Comment: (I'm not sure why it doesn't use 60fps, possibly not supported...? But I still need to know which devices are present in **/dev/dri/** anyway)

Comment: `ls /dev/dri` shows `by-path  card0  renderD128`. And yes, using libx264rgb the colors are fine.

Comment: OK, so there just seems to be **/dev/dri/renderD128** you can use anyway... Did the libx264rgb command give you 60fps? If this works as expected (and is fast enough) it may be easier to just use this instead. There may be a problem with the driver or possibly a bug in ffmpeg, I don't know... - But you can probably fix the colors for hardware-encoding when using 10bit (if your GPU supports it) `ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0 -vf 'format=p010,hwupload' -c:v h264_vaapi -qp 24 output.mp4` may work (but can't test it myself)

Comment: Software encoding gives me 60 fps, I'll just use that.

Comment: What is `hwupload`?

Answer (score 1):

This was asked yesterday and the answer remains the same: HW video codecs do not support changing the quantization factor, i.e. `crf` and more so they don't support lossless encoding.

From https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI

> **Mapping options from libx264**
>
> No CRF-like mode is currently supported. The only constant-quality mode is CQP (constant quantisation parameter), which has no adaptivity to scene content. It does, however, allow different quality settings for different frame types, to improve compression by spending fewer bits on unreferenced B-frames - see the (i|b)_q(factor|offset) options. CQP mode cannot be combined with a maximum bitrate or buffer size.

Comment: I've tried using qcp, as you can see in both of my example commands.

Comment: Whatever you use, the HW codec has strict limitations you cannot work around. There are no transistors to give you what you want. The CPU can do anything because it runs general instructions which could be any. I can imagine some codecs could be accelerated using CUDA or OpenCL but I haven't seen them. Something like that is discussed here http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=164960 The performance improvements are extremely minor if any because you need to copy a lot of data to the GPU.

Comment: From https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=174992 Why doesn't x265 use the GPU in encoding? *And IIRC data transfer is a bottleneck. You can spend more time transfering data between CPU and GPU than doing the operation on CPU directly.*

Comment: GPUs are for massively parallel local computations with low complexity (not too much branching) not involving the system memory. CPUs on the other hand have insane branching prediction capability, so can do anything but only in single threaded mode.

Comment: I know the GPU can physically do what I want as it works in OBS on Windows. I want to know how to do it on Linux. Also my second example uses kmsgrab, which according to the ffmpeg page I linked, does the encoding locally without copying using the cpu.